# Opamp input from transformer

Tags: operational-amplifier, common-mode

Is it possible to connect the circuit like this.
[image]

The circuit is from the resolver input circuit, It takes the sine (or cosine) signal from the output of resolver and reduce to appropriate voltage for controller IC to handle.

For example, if the input voltage of this circuit is 1Vpp then the output voltage will be 0.5Vpp, but how much will the DC bias of output voltage be.

Comment: Those are very low resistor values for an op-amp. Typically R1 is 10K or higher, as it counts as a load on the output combined with an actual load. Only current feedback op-amps have such low values, as they may have to pass signals of several hundred MHZ.

Comment: The output is differential, so using a differential amplifier seems OK. But, as stated in the 1st comment, using 500R and 1k for voltage gain of 2 may not be a good way. You can safely increase those resistors to a few tens or even hundreds of kOhms.

Answer (score 1):

The DC bias at the output will be approximately 0 V or as close as the op-amp can get to it. Instead of R3 to ground perhaps you could have 1k to ground and 1k to VCC. This gives the same effective resistance as before but should bring everything up to half rail. A negative supply to the op-amp should also work.